# one ModelAttribute two controllers

Tags: spring-mvc

i want to display same list of records in my two different page,

### First Controller and JSP

```
public class Model1Controller{

....
....

@ModelAttribute("/myList")
public ModelAndView myMethod(){
   List<String> listOfRecords = new ArrayList<String>();
   listOfRecords.add("1");
   listOfRecords.add("2");

   ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
   mv.addObject("listOfRecords", listOfRecords);

   return mv;
}

....
....
....

}
```

### First JSP

```
<ul>
<c:forEach items="${listOfRecords}" var="items">
  <li${items}></li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

### Second Controller and JSP

```
public class Model1Controller{

....
....

@ModelAttribute("/myList")
public ModelAndView myMethod(){
   List<String> listOfRecords = new ArrayList<String>();
   listOfRecords.add("1");
   listOfRecords.add("2");

   ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
   mv.addObject("listOfRecords", listOfRecords);

   return mv;
}

....
....
....

}
```

### Second JSP

```
<ul>
<c:forEach items="${listOfRecords}" var="items">
  <li${items}></li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

is there any way to access same modelattribute in one place to access

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the same list available to multiple controllers, put it in the session or application context.  Whatever is more appropriate.  The model is a part of the request for anything you want to expose to the web view so it is not designed to be used across multiple requests or controllers.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html

Comment: any examples for putting modelattribute in session or application context. please give me a examples link that should be apriciated

Comment: You can access the request by putting it as one of the parameters on your RequestMapping or you can auto-wire it if you would like to access it in multiple mappings.  From the request you can get the session or application context to add attributes.